# delete ONE array element by value in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I delete the first element by a value in an array?

```
arr = [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 ] 
#something like:
arr.delete_first(3)
#I would like a result like => [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pass the result of [`Array#find_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-find_index) into [`Array#delete_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at):

```
>> arr.delete_at(arr.find_index(3))

>> arr
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`find_index()` will return the Array index of the first element that matches its argument. `delete_at()` deletes the element from an Array at the specified index.

To prevent `delete_at()` raising a `TypeError` if the index isn't found, you may use a `&&` construct to assign the result of `find_index()` to a variable and use that variable in `delete_at()` if it isn't `nil`. The right side of `&&` won't execute at all if the left side is `false` or `nil`.

```
>> (i = arr.find_index(3)) && arr.delete_at(i)
=> 3
>> (i = arr.find_index(6)) && arr.delete_at(i)
=> nil
>> arr
=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You should check that that the argument of `find_index` is included in the array, otherwise `delete_at` raises a `TypeError` because its argument is `nil`.

Comment: @toro2k Indeed. Alternative added above which avoids the TypeError

Comment: A more compact way could be `arr.delete_at(arr.index(3) || arr.size)`.

Comment: @toro2k That's why Ruby is such a neat language.

Comment: @steenslag sorry for the typo.. find_index()  and index() are aliases of each other I believe. Their source is identical in the docs.

Answer (score -8):

You can also use `:-` operator to remove desired element from the array, e.g.:

```
$> [1, 2, 3, '4', 'foo'] - ['foo']
$> [1, 2, 3, '4']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sadly this will delete all instances of 'foo' from the array

Comment: `x = [1, 1]; x - [1] # => []`. This does not answer the question, which was to explicitly *"delete **ONE** array element by value"*.